# Find all the points when the direction of the maximal variation is known

Tags: calculus

> Find all the points where the direction of the maximal variation of
> the function $f(x) = x^2 + y^2 - 2x -4y$ is $(1,1)$.

I know that the directional derivative $f_u(x,y)$ is maximum when the vecteur $u$ is in the same direction and in the same direction as the gradient of f. So I set $(f_x, f_y) = (1,1)$. From this, I got $x=\frac{3}{2}$ and $y = \frac{5}{2}$. So all the points are just $(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{2})$. It seems it is not the only answer, but I am not sure how to find the other points. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} 2 x  - 2 \\ 2 y - 4 \end{bmatrix} $

$ \nabla f = \alpha \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore, $ 2 x - 2 = 2 y - 4 $ which is the line $ x - y + 1 = 0 $.  This line describes all the points with the given property.